# Encrypt credentials JNDI authenticating to JBoss 7.1.1.Final

Tags: security, encryption, jboss, application-server

In my JNDI Lookup, connecting to JBoss 7.1.1.Final from remote clients with plain text password is working fine.

Now, I am trying to encrypt credentials in the form, but it's not working.

```
#=======================================================================
#             JNDI Configuration For EJB3.1
#=======================================================================

org.mycom.user.server.j2ee.UserSHome=myproj/myproj-user-server-j2ee//User!org.mycom.user.server.j2ee.UserSHome

java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true

java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
```

**Without encryption:**

```
java.naming.security.principal=user1

java.naming.security.credentials=pwduser1
```

**With encryption:**

```
java.naming.security.principal=user1

java.naming.security.credentials=73437d00520f1768fcd97a2074c95be9
```

**Encryption logic:**

```
<%JBOSS-HOME%>/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties
```

Please help to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.